# Creating a Template in MS Project

Tags: ms-project

My work consists of a number of nearly identical projects and I'm wondering if I can create some kind of template in Microsoft Project. Hopefully this isn't too stupid a question as I've only ever really opened Project a few times.

Each of the projects is a fixed number of sequential tasks leading to a final synchronisation, but for each there are a few key differences:

The number of initial threads that join at the end

The start and deadline dates

The people doing each of the individual tasks

I'd like to create a template that I could set the number of threads, have it create a little gantt chart view, and then I could start work on assigning tasks.

As a side note, does Project integrate with Outlook and have a list of people/send them things to do?

Comment: Have you tried to locate information about MS-Project templates (using Google for example)? What templating problems remain after you tried the techniques you found?

Comment: I've searched for, and can successfully create a basic template for a project that's almost identical to a project that I create. Searching for "ms project template creation" taught me this, but none of the tutorials seem to have an advanced or further link. I'm struggling though to be asked how many initial threads I want, and to get it to scale the whole project based on start and end dates.

Comment: I'm sorry you've lost me- what is the "number of threads" issue? I have never had to deal with anything to do with threads when creating MS Project, err, projects... Are you working programmatically?

Comment: No, sorry it relates to my project. I mean that there are between one and ten chains of events that all lead to one big review session. I was hoping to create each of the chains from a template

Comment: MS-Project templates are just boilerplate projects that are initialised when creating a new project based on that template. It sounds like you are expecting to be able to synthesize the totality of a Project by combining template tasks (with their attendant sub-tasks). Ms-Project does not support that functionality as far as I know. Incidentally it would help others, who may have better answers than me, if you tagged your question with the MS-Project version you are using.

Comment: Another point- you said you have "only opened Project a few times"- Project is a flexible, and fairly complex, project planning and tracking tool. If your projects are "nearly identical", very predictable and always proceed using the same levels of resourcing over the same durations then it is possible MS-Project is a hammer to crack a nut and may not actually be well suited for your needs. You might want to try just using it a bit more to find out how it is used to check you are not wasting your time?

Comment: Thanks for checking and letting me know. I've been told to use it, and so it'll have to be the hammer this time, nuts be damned!

Answer (score 2):

You can save any MS Project file and call it a "template" for future work.  You'll also want to build a checklist of steps to take when using such a template, for example, (in MS Project 2013)

1. File->Info->Project Information->Set start date
2. File->Resource->Resource Sheet-> Add and remove resources as required
3. In GANTT chart view, change the name of task  ...
4. Other per project customizations as needed.

If there is indeed a lot of common content between these plans, you could save yourself some time.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like I can do the simpler parts of what I need and will have to do the remainder by hand each time.

Comment: Scott is spot on.  The variability of the number of objects you need you can work with by copy/paste summary level tasks to capture the subtask work.  Keep your tasks automatically scheduled so changes in durations or work will update the linked tasks.